# echo variable in html form

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to echo a value in a form based on number of rows returned from database query. Keep getting error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting ',' or ';'

As you can probably tell I'm pretty new to this. Can anyone help me echo the variable? I know that $num_rows is returning a value as using var_dump shows. Thanks

```
<?

if($num_rows <= 10) {

echo '</br></br><form id="h1" class="rounded" action="4.php" target="" 
method="post"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit"  class="button" value="10" /><br>
<input type="text" name="number_of_tests" value="'echo $num_rows;'"/>
</form>';
 }
if($num_rows >10) {
echo '</br></br><form id="h2" class="rounded" action="4.php"    
target="_blank" method="post"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit"  class="button" value="11"/><BR>
<input type="text" name="number_of_tests" value="'echo $num_rows;'"/>

</form>';
}?>
```

Comment: Whenever you get syntax errors that you don't understand, the first thing to do is to start removing (or commenting out) bits of code until the message goes away.  The last thing you removed was probably the cause of the issue.

Comment: Also, the parser tells you *where* it encounters the syntax error (source file, line number and error description)

Comment: parser identifies error on line 40 which is my echo $num_rows. Still not understanding why value="'echo $num_rows;'" doesn't work inside the echoed form...?

Comment: If you are in html mode, you could do value='<?php echo $num_rows;?>'>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both of your code blocks, you repeat the command echo instead of either concatenating the output or using two statements.  You have done this:

```
echo '</br></br><form id="h1" class="rounded" action="4.php" target="" 
method="post"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit"  class="button" value="10" /><br>
<input type="text" name="number_of_tests" value="'echo $num_rows;'"/>
</form>';
```

which is a syntax error.  Instead, you can do this:

```
echo '</br></br><form id="h1" class="rounded" action="4.php" target="" 
method="post"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit"  class="button" value="10" /><br>
<input type="text" name="number_of_tests" value="' . $num_rows . '"/>
</form>';
```

or this:

```
echo '</br></br><form id="h1" class="rounded" action="4.php" target="" 
method="post"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit"  class="button" value="10" /><br>
<input type="text" name="number_of_tests" value="';
echo $num_rows . '"/>';
echo '</form>';
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Been driving me mad. Still not sure I understand how it works if I'm honest!

Comment: echo some_string . some_string . some_string; is allowed.  What's not is adding another echo to the end.  One echo is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code you should use to concatenate strings and output the result

```
echo ' some value ' . $variable . ' other text ';
```

The `echo` function outputs a string, while the dot (.) operator concatenates strings. This is the kind of **wrong code**

```
echo 'value="'echo $num_rows;'"/>';
```

When you want to insert the value of a variable this is the way

```
$a_string = 'I\'m a string';
echo "I'm a double quoted string and can contain a variable: $a_string";
```

This works with arrays too

```
$an_array = array('one', 'two', 'three');
echo "The first element of the array is {$an_array[0]}"
```

See [the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)